# Load array with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an array that holds LatLng location cords,I want to be able to load the array when the user enter the app again.

this is my saving function:

```
protected boolean saveCordArray() {
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME2,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(30f,40f);
    editor.putFloat("position_lat", (float) currentPosition.latitude );
    editor.putFloat("position_lon", (float) currentPosition.longitude);
    editor.commit();
    Log.e("saveCordArray","Saved");
    return editor.commit();
}
```

and this is my array loader

```
public ArrayList<LatLng> getCordArray() {

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME2,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    LatLng loaded_position = new LatLng(20,20);
    float set2 = sharedpreferences.getFloat("position_lat",15);
    sharedpreferences.getFloat("position_lon", 15f); new HashSet<String>();
    Log.v("lastposition", "loaded position: ("+loaded_position.latitude+","+loaded_position.longitude+")" );


    return new ArrayList<LatLng>((int) set2);
}
```

I think the problem is with the array loader,because I get the message "Saved" in the log.
Where am I wrong ?

Thanks guys

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error? The returned array is empty? Be specific.

Comment: the position is not loading,I get no errors or crashes ..

Comment: So the returned array from getCordArray() is empty? *Be specific*.